# Need my CRT work spot-checked

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

So I have a bunch of equations that look like this:

$$k + tx \equiv a \bmod m$$

Where $t$ is the common variable I am solving for among the equations (each equation may have different values for $k,x,a,m$). Before I apply CRT I am processing the equations a bit. Is what I am doing correct:

1. Check if $g =\gcd(x,m)$ divides $a-k$. If not, there's no solution.
2. Divide everything by $g$, giving us equation $tx/g \equiv (a-k)/g \bmod m/g$, which I will relabel as $tX \equiv A \bmod M$.
3. Now that $X$ and $M$ are coprime, reframe as $t \equiv AX^{-1} \bmod M$, relabel as $t \equiv R \bmod M$.

At this point:

-Have I done things correctly?

-Are there any more quick "checks" I should apply or simplifications to use before I begin the CRT process to find $t$?

-Namely, do I need to do another gcd test? Finding the gcd of $R$ and $M$ and then dividing?

Comment: Is anything in my question unclear?

Comment: What you have so far looks really good and complete, in that the final modular equation is exactly equivalent to the original.  One remaining step is to reduce the system of equations so that the moduli are pairwise co-prime (either by breaking each $M$ into prime powers, or finding common factors between all the $M$s). But you might consider that to be part of the CRT process, so it isn't necessarily missing.